# Issues with upgrading spring boot from 2.4.4 to 2.7.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, java-11

Due to spring-boot EOL of older version,
I am trying to upgrade spring boot version from 2.4.4 to 2.7.1 and getting below exception.
It was working perfectly on 2.4.4 and now when I bootrun this service, it does not start.
Below is the exception stacktrace for same.

Could someone help on how to resolve this below error.

```
SEVERE: Failed to destroy the filter named [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter] of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract destroy()V of interface javax.servlet.Filter.
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:303)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4647)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5469)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:986)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1401)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:986)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:497)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:982)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:496)
       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:273)
       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:331)
       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
       at com.test.csp.as.Application.main(Application.java:63)
```

Below is the dependency tree for the versions being used:

```
+--- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12 -> 2.0.0-alpha6
+--- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6 -> 1.18.4
+--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 31.0-jre
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4 -> 3.11
|    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.5 -> 2.10.8
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.6.3 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.3 -> 2.13.3 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.3 -> 2.13.3 (*)
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.6.3 -> 2.13.3
+--- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.7.0
+--- ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:1.4.6
+--- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.4.1
+--- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:9.9.1-7
+--- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.2
+--- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:2.0-beta4
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.7
+--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7 (*)
+--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:10.0.5 -> 11.0.10
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-http4:3.10.0 -> 2.25.4
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-jms:3.10.0
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-javaconfig:3.10.0
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:3.10.0
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-velocity:3.10.0
+--- org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core:2.3
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:3.10.0
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-ws:3.10.0
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-soap:3.10.0
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.26.Final
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-mail:3.10.0
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.5
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6 -> 3.11
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3
\--- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:1.9.10 -> 1.9.11
|    +--- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.6.0
|    +--- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:4.39.1 -> 7.9
|    +--- com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:2.0.0
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.1.1.RELEASE
|    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1 -> 2.3.2 (*)
|    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
|    \--- io.zipkin.brave:brave:5.1.4
+--- com.oracle:ojdbc:6
+--- com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java7:2.4.12
+--- io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.1 (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.1
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services:2.7.1
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.1 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.1.2.RELEASE
+--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.12.RELEASE -> 5.3.6 (*)
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12 -> 2.0.0-alpha6
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.7
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.16.Final -> 5.4.26.Final (*)
+--- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA
+--- javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.1.7.Final
+--- org.codehaus.janino:janino:2.6.1
+--- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:2.0
+--- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.5 -> 1.6.0 (*)
+--- com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api:com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.distributedMap:2.0.11
+--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.1
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.7.0 -> 2.7.1 (*)
```

Comment: 1. Read the uprade notes from all the versions, 2. don't try to outsmart the dependency management done by Spring Boot (judging by the dependencies in there and the version resolution is what you do).

Answer (score 0):

The first version of Camel Spring Boot supporting Spring Boot 2.7.x is the 3.18.0, so you should also upgrade Camel version to 3.18.0 and not only upgrading Spring Boot to 2.7.1